# PCB coil electromagnet driver

Tags: pcb, electromagnetism

[image: System Design]

Based on external sensor inputs, I want to vertically pulldown & release (in a controlled manner) a 7mm neodymium magnet enclosed inside a circular elastic diaphragm. I want to keep the size as minimal as possible (around 20 mm in diameter). For this, I want to make a PCB coil electro magnet. The elastic diaphragm would be placed about 7mm to 10mm  above this PCB coil.  I want to power this preferably with 3.5V or 5V.

Can you please tell if this would work ? and also can you please suggest how to design a circuit to drive the PCB electro magnet ? Any pointers would be very helpful.

Hope the above description makes sense.

Comment: What kind of core are you using for the electromagnet?

Comment: How much does the magnet weigh and how many turns do you have?

Comment: As a first impression, the impedance of that coil will be *very* low - so low you will probably have problems exciting it with a normal audio amplifier. Speaker coils use the iron from the speaker to have more inductance.

Comment: For the PCB coil here is a [designer tool](http://webench.ti.com/wb5/LDC/#/spirals?lang_chosen=en_US&shape=Circular&dout=400&layers=2&turns=16), it may will be useful. Exportable design into Altium Designer, Cadence Allegro 16.0-16.5, CadSoft EAGLE PCB (v6.4 or newer), DesignSpark PCB, Mentor Graphics PADS PCB.

Comment: *I want to power this preferably with 3.5V or 5V.* The driver circuit can use a boost voltage converter, no matter the external power source.  So the supply voltage requirement is "soft".

Answer (score 2):

A coil energized with current can create a force of attraction to an iron object. It can also repel a magnet if the polarity is correct. That force is: -

Force = \$\dfrac{(amps\cdot turns)^2\cdot \mu_0\cdot A}{2\cdot g^2}\$

Where

- A is cross sectional area of the electromagnet
- g is gap to your magnet
- \$\mu_0\$ is 4\$\pi\$ x \$10^{-7}\$

Let's say the force needed is 0.2 newtons. Your required coil is 20mm in diameter and lets assume that all the turns are closely packed around a diameter of 20mm. The gap to the magnet is 10mm. Lets say you can get 100 turns wound at this diameter...

Re-writing: -

Amps = \$\sqrt{\dfrac{20 \cdot 2 \cdot 0.01^2}{100^2\cdot 4\pi \times 10^{-7}\cdot 3.14\times 10^{-4}}}
\$

That's about 32 amps.

But, it's going to be a lot worse for a spiral design because as the coil diameter gets tighter (for the inner turns), the effective area of the electromagnet gets smaller.

I think you might be looking at something like 100 amps for a 100 turn coil and basically it looks unfeasible. Of course, if your force is significantly less than 0.2 newtons then the amperage would drop so plug your own numbers in to the formula.

Once you have got an idea how much current is needed then that is the time to work out how to drive your electromagnet.

Comment: Andy aka and @JCoppens, Thank you the responses. My understanding was that since I am using a neodymium magnet, the amount of force needed to be generated by PCB coil to move the magnet would be less.  Am I misunderstanding anything ?

Comment: You are quite correct but at the distances and dimensions you propose the force may only be 50% of the force needed to attract a piece of iron. This means about 70% of the current is needed. Plus, remember that I made a broad brush estimate of the force required and it could be one tenth of what I assumed meaning a further reduction in current of about 3 to 1. I would urge you to make a simple coil and try it out.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I will make this coil and will try to get a feel of how this works.

Answer (score 0):

As a first impression, the impedance of that coil will be very low - so low you will probably have problems exciting it with a normal audio amplifier. Speaker coils use the iron from the speaker to have more inductance.

If the coil can be 20mm, at 0.3mm trace width, you can have about 15 turns.

Try that in [this calculator](http://www.circuits.dk/calculator_planar_coil_inductor.htm). It gives about 5 uH way too low

Comment: Note that the calculator works in um (micrometer), so 20mm = 20000um